# Quickly verify a large number of domains via whois

Tags: command-line, whois

If I do

```
time whois google.com
```

it takes about a second to come back with a response to if a domain is registered or not.

If I do (a non-existant domain)

```
time whois fslafdjlsadjflsjdf.com
```

It comes back very quickly.

I want to be able to query several thousand domains to verify if they are registered or not (just a simple true/false) and I want to do it quickly.

What is the best way to do this? The fact that the failure comes back so quickly seems to suggest there is something that will give back quick negatives.

Comment: Why a `whois` rather `host`?  `host` will report `NXDOMAIN` and throw a `1` exit code for domains which do not exist.

Comment: I wonder if the whois server(s) rate-limit their requests?

Comment: In what format are the thousand domains? A file? An array?

Comment: @JeffSchaller They usually do...and if you insist in that behaviour you will probably get quickly blocked. They do not fancy getting their services (ab)used.

Comment: @DopeGhoti host throws an nxdomain for registered domains that whois has as registered, such as kat.com

Comment: @JeffSchaller an array in javascript in node.js

Comment: @RuiFRibeiro is there a better way? I just want to run a large list through and see what is registered and what is not.